# Doing the Drag and Drop from one Grid to Another Grid made Form elements Irregular

Tags: ext.net

> Hi, I am Implementing the Drag Drop functionality using the Link
>   http://examples.ext.net/#/DragDrop/Grid/Grid_to_Grid/
>
> and i have implemented this on my form as when i click on One Grid
>   Column setting Icon that gridpanel should be hide and this
>   panel(ID:pnlGridDragDrop)  which are containing two DragDrop grids
>   should be visible.
>
> after Displaying the pnlGridDragDrop when i trying to Drag items from
>   first Grid to another the above Tab Design becomes disappear.
>
> What is the Reason here.
>
> Please find the Image i have attached and the Code in my Program is as
>   like below.

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="grdProjectsView"  Width="705" Title="Projects" >
---
columns
------
 <ext:ImageCommandColumn ID="imgSettings"   runat="server" Text="Settings" Resizable="false">
    <Commands>
     <ext:ImageCommand Icon="BasketEdit" Style="text-align: center" CommandName="Settings">
          </ext:ImageCommand>
       </Commands>
      <Listeners>
    <Command Handler="#{DirectMethods}.fnDisplaySettings(record.data.ProjectID,record.data.ProjectName);" />
         </Listeners>
       </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
  ---
    ---
 </ColumnModel>
 </ext:GridPanel>


// Drag Drop Grids Panel

 <ext:Panel ID="pnlProjMemberGrid" runat="server" Border="false">
      <LayoutConfig>
            <ext:HBoxLayoutConfig Align="Stretch" Padding="5" />
      </LayoutConfig>
      <Items>
          <ext:GridPanel   ID="grdNonProjectEmloyeeList">
        </ext:GridPanel>
       <ext:GridPanel   ID="grdProjectEmloyeeList">
      </ext:GridPanel>
```

> Thank you.
>   [image]

Comment: Can you provide full sample to reproduce?

Comment: It's Ok i got it by providing Height to Every panel that Issue is gone. But if the Sceen Resolution is low this issue reappears. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to adjust the Heights of the panels/Container